# Iterating through dictionary keys when the keys point to an array?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, iteration

I made a dictionary where each key references an array.  And I'm trying to apply a .loc command to each array, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.  Was wondering how this can be done:

```
#setup:
import pandas as pd
psd = pd.read_csv('psd.csv')
psd.head()

Out[43]: 
        id group   band       fp1  ...        fz        cz        pz        oz
0  3407906   Cu-  delta  0.291945  ...  0.230908  0.221589  0.247830  0.229259
1  3407906   Cu-  theta  0.022924  ...  0.026598  0.036143  0.029904  0.025336
2  3407906   Cu-  alpha  0.003124  ...  0.017416  0.015175  0.015207  0.028024
3  3407906   Cu-   beta  0.000573  ...  0.005325  0.006429  0.003628  0.003757
4  3407906   Cu-  gamma  0.000485  ...  0.002627  0.002037  0.000956  0.001303

gp = dict(tuple(psd.groupby('band')))
list(gp.keys())

Out[44]: ['alpha', 'beta', 'delta', 'gamma', 'theta']

for key in gp: 
    print(gp[key].head(1))

Out[45]:
        id group   band       fp1  ...        fz        cz        pz        oz
2  3407906   Cu-  alpha  0.003124  ...  0.017416  0.015175  0.015207  0.028024

[1 rows x 32 columns]
        id group  band       fp1  ...        fz        cz        pz        oz
3  3407906   Cu-  beta  0.000573  ...  0.005325  0.006429  0.003628  0.003757

[1 rows x 32 columns]
        id group   band       fp1  ...        fz        cz       pz        oz
0  3407906   Cu-  delta  0.291945  ...  0.230908  0.221589  0.24783  0.229259

[1 rows x 32 columns]
        id group   band       fp1  ...        fz        cz        pz        oz
4  3407906   Cu-  gamma  0.000485  ...  0.002627  0.002037  0.000956  0.001303

[1 rows x 32 columns]
        id group   band       fp1  ...        fz        cz        pz        oz
1  3407906   Cu-  theta  0.022924  ...  0.026598  0.036143  0.029904  0.025336
```

So far so good, but when I try the following:

```
for key in gp:
    band = gp[key]
    x_band = band.loc[:,'fp1':'oz']

x_band.head()
Out[49]: 
         fp1        f3        f7  ...        cz        pz        oz
1   0.022924  0.019966  0.021740  ...  0.036143  0.029904  0.025336
6   0.028581  0.026947  0.025785  ...  0.028249  0.028188  0.025704
11  0.005078  0.001958  0.003227  ...  0.002071  0.002150  0.002991
16  0.014026  0.030532  0.018575  ...  0.036702  0.027133  0.020489
21  0.002640  0.001335  0.002605  ...  0.001256  0.001974  0.003032
```

The result as you can see is only for the last key/array, rather than a dictionary of 5 arrays with the band.loc command applied to it.  I could/did just do this manually and ended up with 5 different arrays.  But is there a way to keep it in dictionary format so I don't have to do everything from this step out 5 times?  Happy to clarify, sorry this is weirdly worded.

Comment: The reason x_band is always the last entry is because it is overwritten each time the loop executes. You can try to add a list:

`
x_bands = []

for key in gp:
    band = gp[key]
    x_band = band.loc[:,'fp1':'oz']
    x_bands.append(x_band)
`

Comment: You should probably tag this question with the library that's providing your `psd` object's datatype. You're calling a bunch of methods on that object (and other objects its methods return) and what exactly they mean isn't necessarily obvious to anyone who doesn't know the library.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me what you mean by "keep it in dictionary format." Do you want to do `gp[key] = band.loc[...]`? You seem to already know what's wrong with the code you've shown (that you're overwriting the same variable name, `x_band` on each pass of the loop without doing anything with it). But it's not clear what you actually want to do.

Comment: Thanks! I kind of figured that was the case but couldn't figure out how to get around it.  I did have to apply a dictionary zip to get it back into the dictionary form: `psd_gp = dict(zip(gp.keys(), x_bands))` Frankly leaving it in the list form is probably easier to deal with for what I need to do with it, and I'm not being picky because this definitely worked, but I'm curious, is this a way to do this while keeping it in the dictionary form without having to do that intervening step of creating a list?  In case this comes up later.